# MPMoviePlayerViewController Not Rotating until app restart

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, rotation

K here is an interesting problem

We have an app that is presenting with unusual behavior

If you install that app (from either test flight or via xcode debug) onto a "clean" device (where the app has not existed before or has been previously delete) when the app plays a mp4 from the web or from local memory. The MPMoviePlayerViewController used to play the app will not rotate.

However if you force quit the app and start it again, everything rotates correctly. Even if you quit and return without closing the background thread the video will not rotate.

Here is the simple code

```
    mediaController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoPath]];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: mediaController];
    [mediaController release];
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Further investigation shows the shouldRotate method is never being called when the device is rotated.  It is called when the player is presented thus the video is correctly aligned to initial orientation but never changes

Comment: Is the current view controller (self) being presented in a popover or modally?

Comment: This rotation only when starting a second time sounds a lot as if you have some other problems within your app. Did you try to develop a little showcase with as little as possible code to confirm this issue?

Comment: self is the root view of a navigation controller on a tab bar controller.

I am currently trying to setup and narrow down the issue in a test application.  I expect it to be something in my code, but the fact it works every time except the first after the install is what is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue with this.  the UIWindow can only have one view.  If another is added, 2nd views will not receive the notification. I had an action that was triggering on the first load that was doing this causing the views to not rotate.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that one of the root view for another one of the tabs is stopping the root view containing your player from rotating. The UITabBarController asks all its children view controllers (one for each tab) whether it should allow rotation and will only allow one to rotate to a given orientation if all of them allow it. This is done so as to avoid the orientation switching violently from one to another when the user switches tabs. Try putting a breakpoint in the shouldAllowAutoRotation for all of the UITabBarController's children and see if they get called.

Comment: I will check this out, but it doesn't explain why it happens every time except for when the app has just been installed